# Deploy a file to the "Forms" folder of a Document Library using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, deployment, powershell

I am dynamically building up a file that I then want to upload to SharePoint 2013 using PowerShell.

I want to upload this file into the "Forms" folder of a Document Library - So not into the Document Library itself.

I am trying to do this without creating a WSP file - Because I am dynamically creating a file, I just want to upload the resulting file I've created, rather than deploy the file as a feature.

I already have everything to create the file, but I don't know how to upload into the Forms folder for a Document Library.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, maybe you should look for network path and do a simple copy of your file (if you have rights to do it). I'm searching a link I had for this

Comment: Please refer to the post I did, and links that are provided in. It must help you, for sure. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/121522/17814
Just don't forget, that when you get a library in PowerShell, all folders (even subfolders) are listed in the $library.Folders . Idk if I'm understandable.

Comment: Do you mean the Forms folder (The one containing the AllItems.aspx etc.) is available to add files to, once you have a reference to the library?

Comment: I cannot try right now, but as it's a folder like others (look with SharePoint Designers - All Files), I don't see any problem.